# Можно ли выключить ковариантность в делегатах c#

Tags: c#, делегаты

Для чего я явно указываю in/out в обобщенных делегатах, если и без этих ключевых слов они вариантны. Можно ли как-то отключить эту вариантность?

```
del<Child> delegate1 = func; // Contrvariance
del1<Parent> delegate2 = func2; // Covariance

void func(Parent x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

Child func2()
{
    return new Child();
}


class Parent { }
class Child : Parent { }

delegate void del<T>(T item); //without in
delegate K del1<K>(); // without out
```

Comment: А для чего это нужно? Приведите пример, где оно бы потребовалось?

Comment: Книга Framework Design Guidelines, 3-е издание (2020), раздел 9.8 Covariance and Contravariance - подробнейшее объяснение темы из всех, что мне встречались.

Answer (score 0):

ничего отключить нельзя, in/out используются по принципу "nice to have" (источник: с# 9.0 in nutshell)